# Angular test - Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null" on Karma

Tags: angularjs, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am setting several tests on my Angular application and in one of them I am getting this error when trying to get a HTML element: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`

This is a sample of my template:

```
<div *ngIf="parentProps" class="detalhes-container">
  <!-- <p class="teste">teste</p> -->
  <div *ngFor="let info of parentProps.applicationsData; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <p class="teste">teste</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are two `p` tags on it for testing purposes, the first one is commented (it works fine) and the second one is the one I want to make it work.

spec.ts script:

```
describe('ListDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: ListDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ListDetailsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create list details', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('functions', () => {
    component.parentProps = true
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.teste').textContent).toContain('teste');
  })

});
```

The reason I have two `p` tags is because I realized that one of the problems is due the `parentProps` property used by the `*ngIf`, so I set it as `true` in my test, then it worked, however, after this `*ngIf` I also have a block with a `*ngFor` and when I run my test with the tag within this loop I get the same error, so, I believe the problem is the `*ngFor`. With the `*ngIf` I managed to turn around this, but I have no idea how to solve the `*ngFor` problem.

One thing that may be important, the `parentProps` is indeed an object comming from the parent component that I am receiving through an `@Input`.

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make `applicationsData` an array on the object, the object cannot just be true.

Try:

```
it('functions', () => {
    component.parentProps = { applicationsData: ['hello', 'world'] }; // mock applicationsData array.
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.teste').textContent).toContain('teste');
  })
```